# golang тестирование телеграм

Tags: golang, telegram-bot, vpn

Я хочу тестировать своего бота, написанного на golang, для телеграмма на локальной машине.
С включенным VPN проблем нет.
Телеграмм в России заблокирован и при обращении к APi телеграмма выводит timeout panic, но когда включаю в впн, то проблем нет.Может кто знает есть ли способ какой обойти это без впн или может сервис какой который мог бы в этом помочь.

использую впн wincribe, но там определенное кол-во подключений.поэтому и ищу другой способ

Comment: Берёте да обходите. Хотя проблемы как таковой здесь не описано.

Comment: Добавил в описание

Comment: Поместите своего бота на сервера Амазона/Microsoft или куда-то еще, где не нужна VPN.

Comment: Попробуйте [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)